# I want to make a chrome extension that will display the hostname on the popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension that will display the hostname on the popup
but its not working for me

manifest.json

```
{
    "name" : "Chrome ex",
    "description" : "Chrome ex",
    "version" : "6.9",
    "manifest_version" : 3,

    "permissions" : [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup" : "popup.html"
    }

    
}
```

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
    var url = tabs[0];
})
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What error do you get? Anything in the console?

Comment: @MotiKorets Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')
    at <anonymous>

Comment: 1) Don't open popup.html as a file. Click the extension icon to show the popup. 2) The code is almost correct, it should be `var url=tabs[0].url` and then you can show it in the popup using standard DOM methods. 3) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Hey can you mention the dom I should use havent figure it out since yesterday

Comment: document.write("<h1>" + url + "</h1>");